# Testing the user experience: Appium vs XCUITest

Tags: automated-tests, appium, appium-ios, xcuitest

We're building a mobile app and want to decide which testing framework to go ahead with when automating our tests.

I'm making a few assumptions about how a human tester, Appium and XCUITest do their tests. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

- Human: clicks button
- Appium: sends the app a click event for that button
- XCUITest: activates the code that clicking the button would have activated

Therefore Appium is much closer to emulating human behavior than XCUITest. My question is, how big a drawback is this for XCUITest? I want my tests to tell me what the user's experience with my app will be like. What is the risk that I will miss bugs in the app if I test it with XCUITest that I would have caught with Appium?

Answer (score 2):

Appium is based on XCTest. XCTest and Appium are black-box frameworks and their interactions with the app are almost the same. The black-box frameworks are very close to human interactions.

Some grey-box frameworks like EarlGrey can activate the code, unlike the XCTest and Appium, but it is not their default behaviour.

The biggest difference between Appium and XCTest in terms of test execution is performance. XCTest is faster. You can read more about iOS testing frameworks performance here 
https://devexperts.com/blog/ios-ui-testing-frameworks-performance-comparison/